# Setup timeout for commands in Windows .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a windows .bat script. To run a list of commands and then shut down the computer.

such as:

```
c:\someapplication.exe
c:\someapplication2.exe
Shutdown -s -t 0
```

Sometimes, "c:\someapplication.exe" freezes and do not respond. How can I setup timeout for my command "c:\someapplication.exe", so that after a certain amount of time, I want windows to force close the application and continue the rest of the commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of `ping` and `taskkill` to do this.

```
start c:\someapplication.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n seconds
taskkill /im someapplication.exe /f 
start c:\someapplication2.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n seconds
taskkill /im someapplication2.exe /f 
Shutdown -s -t 0 /f
```

Just replace `seconds` in the `ping` command with the number of seconds you want to wait before attempting to close the process (enough time so if it's still running it must have crashed). Then the rest of the app can continue until it is forced to shutdown.

Comment: if someapplication hangs it will not proceed to ping and taskkill

Answer (score 3):

if you may afford that all someapplications run in parallel try this

```
 start someapplication
 start someapplication2
 wait n secons
 shutdown
```

choose your value of n so that it does not proceed with shutdown while someapplications still run legit

or alternatively

```
 start someapplication
 wait n seconds
 start someapplication2
 wait m seconds
 shutdown
```

for `wait` there are many solutions around, google some *bat wait timeout*

Comment: `wait` isn't a command. You can use `timeout` on Windows Vista and later.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your exe program and the shutdown command at once and put the timeout in shutdown options [-t]. 
To run multiple command at once, use "start" command ("start [yourProgram.exe]").
To do force shutdown use [-f] option.

good luck

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is shutdown for shutdowning the entire window system? or for application as well?

Comment: actually shutdown command enables a user to shutdown a windows system (not an application -as i know) locally or as remote computer.
search on google for more help. good luck buddy.